# how to break a while condition for a customized class method in python?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, pyautogui

I am trying to detect a button with the library `pyautogui`, the idea is that while the button is detected just print the iteration trial, and when the button is finally detected then just print the location of the button using `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` and break the iterations.

However, the next code stays forever evaluating first iteration (`0`) and it never evaluates the subsequent `if` condition:

```
import pyautogui
import os

def button_detector():
    for i in range(450):
        some_button=pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, r'some_button.png'), region=(0, 510, 547, 153) , grayscale=False)
            
        while some_button is None:
              print('Button not found at trial {}'.format(i))
              print('Error: did not find any button')
                     
              if some_button is not None:
                 print(some_button)
                 print("Button detected")
                 break
```

How could I possible break the while condition in order to accomplish this task?

Is there any other simpler way to do it?

Comment: You need to reassign `some_button` inside the loop, otherwise it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `while` loop? You already have the `for` loop.

Comment: I'd also recommend you to implement some sleep function etc. Otherwise the while loop will run as fast as your processor can and this is pretty unnecessary ressource consumption.

Comment: @Markus 450 iterations will complete almost instantly.

Comment: @Barmar: 450 is the `for`-loop. The `while`-loop seems to be intended to run until `some_button` is not none, thus, until its created or somewhat else. This will run as long as necessary at as much hz as possible.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `for` and `while` - if you want to check button 450 times then you should rander use `if` instead of `while`

Comment: if you really need `while` then you should use again `locateOnScreen` inside `while` to update value in `some_button`. Your corrent code runs `locateOnScreen` only once and it assign value to `some_button` only once - and `while` can't change this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you use `for` and `while` but for me it should be `if/else` instead of `while` and nested `if`.

```
import pyautogui
import os

def button_detector():
    path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'some_button.png')
    
    for i in range(450):
          some_button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(path, region=(0, 510, 547, 153) , grayscale=False)
        
          if some_button is None:
              print('Button not found at trial {}'.format(i))
              print('Error: did not find any button')
          else:       
              print(some_button)
              print("Button detected")
              break
```

But as for me it would need rather `return some_button` instead of `break`

```
import pyautogui
import os

def button_detector():
    path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'some_button.png')
    
    for i in range(450):
          some_button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(path, region=(0, 510, 547, 153) , grayscale=False)
        
          if some_button is None:
              print('Button not found at trial {}'.format(i))
              print('Error: did not find any button')
          else:       
              print(some_button)
              print("Button detected")
              return some_button

# --- main ---

pos = button_detector()

if pos:
    print('button detected at position', pos)       
else:     
    print('button NOT detected')
```

Or with less `prints` and with `sleep` because code may runs too fast.

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time

def button_detector():
    path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'some_button.png')
    
    for i in range(450):
          some_button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(path, region=(0, 510, 547, 153), grayscale=False)
        
          if some_button:
              return some_button

          #time.sleep(0.1) # to wait little longer
          
# --- main ---

pos = button_detector()

if pos:
    print('button detected at position', pos)       
else:     
    print('button NOT detected')
```

---

**EDIT:**

I checked source code for [locateOnScreen](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/pyautogui/__init__.py#L213) and it uses function
[pyscreeze.locateOnScreen](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L350) which has option `minSearchTime` - so if you want to wait longer for button - ie. 3 seconds then you can use

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen(..., minSearchTime=3)
```

and it will run loop which will check it again and again for 3 seconds - and you don't have to create own loop.

```
import pyautogui
import os

def button_detector():
    path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'some_button.png')
    return pyautogui.locateOnScreen(path, region=(0, 510, 547, 153), 
                                    grayscale=False, minSearchTime=3)

# --- main ---

pos = button_detector()

if pos:
    print('button detected at position', pos)       
else:     
    print('button NOT detected')
```

or simpler

import pyautogui
import os

```
# --- main ---

pos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'some_button.png'), 
                               region=(0, 510, 547, 153), 
                               grayscale=False, 
                               minSearchTime=3)


if pos:
    print('button detected at position', pos)       
else:     
    print('button NOT detected')
```